# query to keep partitions separate when physically separated

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table that contains order/shipment history.  A basic dummy version is:

```
ORDERS
order_no | order_stat | stat_date 
 2       | Planned    |  01-Jan-2000
 2       | Picked     |  15-Jan-2000
 2       | Planned    |  17-Jan-2000
 2       | Planned    |  05-Feb-2000
 2       | Planned    |  31-Mar-2000
 2       | Picked     |  05-Apr-2000
 2       | Shipped    |  10-Apr-2000
```

I need to figure out how long each order has been in each order status/phase.  The only problem is when I create a partition on the order_no and order_stat, I get results that make sense but are not what I am looking for.

My sql:

```
 select
    order_no
    ,order_stat
    ,stat_date
    ,lag(stat_date, 1) over (partition by order_no order by stat_date) prev_stat_date
    ,stat_date - lag(stat_date, 1) over (partition by order_no order by stat_date) date_diff
    ,row_number() over(partition by order_no, order_stat order by stat_date) rnk
 from
    orders
```

Will give me the following results:

```
order_no | order_stat | stat_date     | prev_stat_date  |    rnk     
 2       | Planned    |  01-Jan-2000  |                 |  1
 2       | Picked     |  15-Jan-2000  |  01-Jan-2000    |  1
 2       | Planned    |  17-Jan-2000  |  15-Jan-2000    |  2
 2       | Planned    |  05-Feb-2000  |  17-Jan-2000    |  3
 2       | Planned    |  31-Mar-2000  |  05-Feb-2000    |  4
 2       | Picked     |  05-Apr-2000  |  31-Mar-2000    |  2
 2       | Shipped    |  10-Apr-2000  |  05-Apr-2000    |  1
```

I would like to have results that look like this (the rnk starts over when it reverts back to a previous order stat):

```
order_no | order_stat | stat_date     | prev_stat_date  |    rnk     
 2       | Planned    |  01-Jan-2000  |                 |  1
 2       | Picked     |  15-Jan-2000  |  01-Jan-2000    |  1
 2       | Planned    |  17-Jan-2000  |  15-Jan-2000    |  1
 2       | Planned    |  05-Feb-2000  |  17-Jan-2000    |  2
 2       | Planned    |  31-Mar-2000  |  05-Feb-2000    |  3
 2       | Picked     |  05-Apr-2000  |  31-Mar-2000    |  1
 2       | Shipped    |  10-Apr-2000  |  05-Apr-2000    |  1
```

I'm trying to get a running total count of how long it has been in the status (that starts over even if the status it changes to has existed previously instead of being included in the previous partition) but I have no idea how to approach this.  Any and all insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your output doesn't match your query. Do you actually want the ranks, or are you just trying to get those as an intermediate step? It might be helpful to show the result you are trying to achieve overall - i.e. what you want the `date_diif` to show, if that's your end goal.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this is a gaps-and-islands problem.

The difference of row numbers can be used to identify the "island"s and then to enumerate the values:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by order_no, order_stat, seqnum - seqnum_2 order by stat_date) as your_rank
from (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by order_no order by stat_date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by order_no, order_stat order by stat_date) as seqnum_2
      from orders o
     ) t;
```

I've left out the other columns (like the `lag()`) so you can see the logic.  It can be a bit hard to follow why this works.  If you stare at some rows from the subquery, you will probably see how the difference of the row numbers defines the groups you want.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing @Gordon's [Tabibitosan](http://rwijk.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/tabibitosan.html) approach, once you have the groupings you can get both the order within each group and the elapsed number of days for each member of the group:

```
-- CTE for sample data
with orders (order_no, order_stat, stat_date) as (
            select 2, 'Planned', date '2000-01-01' from dual
  union all select 2, 'Picked',  date '2000-01-15' from dual
  union all select 2, 'Planned', date '2000-01-17' from dual
  union all select 2, 'Planned', date '2000-02-05' from dual
  union all select 2, 'Planned', date '2000-03-31' from dual
  union all select 2, 'Picked ', date '2000-04-05' from dual
  union all select 2, 'Shipped', date '2000-04-10' from dual
)
-- actual query
select order_no, order_stat, stat_date, grp,
  dense_rank() over (partition by order_no, order_stat, grp order by stat_date) as rnk,
  stat_date - min(stat_date) keep (dense_rank first order by stat_date)
                over (partition by order_no, order_stat, grp) as stat_days
from (
  select order_no, order_stat, stat_date,
    row_number() over (partition by order_no order by stat_date)
      - row_number() over (partition by order_no, order_stat order by stat_date) as grp
  from orders
)
order by order_no, stat_date;

  ORDER_NO ORDER_S STAT_DATE         GRP        RNK  STAT_DAYS
---------- ------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         2 Planned 2000-01-01          0          1          0
         2 Picked  2000-01-15          1          1          0
         2 Planned 2000-01-17          1          1          0
         2 Planned 2000-02-05          1          2         19
         2 Planned 2000-03-31          1          3         74
         2 Picked  2000-04-05          5          1          0
         2 Shipped 2000-04-10          6          1          0
```

The inline view is essentially what Gordon did, except it trivially does the subtraction at that level. The outer query then gets the rank the same way, but also uses an analytic function to get the earliest date for that group, and subtracts it from the current row's date. You don't have to include `grp` or `rnk` in your final result of course, they're shown to give more insight into what's happening.

It isn't clear exactly what you want, but you can expand even further to, for instance:

```
with cte1 (order_no, order_stat, stat_date, grp) as (
  select order_no, order_stat, stat_date,
    row_number() over (partition by order_no order by stat_date)
      - row_number() over (partition by order_no, order_stat order by stat_date)
  from orders
),
cte2 (order_no, order_stat, stat_date, grp, grp_date, rnk) as (
  select order_no, order_stat, stat_date, grp,
    min(stat_date) keep (dense_rank first order by stat_date)
      over (partition by order_no, order_stat, grp),
    dense_rank() over (partition by order_no, order_stat, grp order by stat_date)
  from cte1
)
select order_no, order_stat, stat_date, grp, grp_date, rnk,
  stat_date - grp_date as stat_days_so_far,
  case
    when order_stat != 'Shipped' then
      coalesce(first_value(stat_date)
                 over (partition by order_no order by grp_date
                   range between 1 following and unbounded following), trunc(sysdate))
        - min(stat_date) keep (dense_rank first order by stat_date)
            over (partition by order_no, order_stat, grp)
  end as stat_days_total,
  stat_date - min(stat_date) over (partition by order_no) as order_days_so_far,
  case
    when max(order_stat) keep (dense_rank last order by stat_date)
           over (partition by order_no) = 'Shipped' then
      max(stat_date) over (partition by order_no)
    else
      trunc(sysdate)
  end
    - min(stat_date) over (partition by order_no) as order_days_total
from cte2
order by order_no, stat_date;
```

which for your sample data gives:

```
  ORDER_NO ORDER_S STAT_DATE         GRP GRP_DATE          RNK STAT_DAYS_SO_FAR STAT_DAYS_TOTAL ORDER_DAYS_SO_FAR ORDER_DAYS_TOTAL
---------- ------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------- --------------- ----------------- ----------------
         2 Planned 2000-01-01          0 2000-01-01          1                0              14                 0              100
         2 Picked  2000-01-15          1 2000-01-15          1                0               2                14              100
         2 Planned 2000-01-17          1 2000-01-17          1                0              79                16              100
         2 Planned 2000-02-05          1 2000-01-17          2               19              79                35              100
         2 Planned 2000-03-31          1 2000-01-17          3               74              79                90              100
         2 Picked  2000-04-05          5 2000-04-05          1                0               5                95              100
         2 Shipped 2000-04-10          6 2000-04-10          1                0                               100              100
```

I've included some logic to assume that 'Shipped' is the final status, and if that hasn't been reached then the last status is still running - so counting up to today. That might be wrong, and you might have other end-status values (e.g. cancelled). Anyway, a few things for you to explore and play with...

You might be able to do something similar with `match_recognize`, but I'll leave that to someone else.